# Installshield - checking for key in registry failed with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, installshield

I have an Installshield project with powershell CA that checks if certain registry key exists and set a property base on the result.

The registry check succeeded when executing the script manually but failed (return `false` when get executed from Installshield.

** The CA is being executed during the UI sequence (before the `ExecuteAction` step) - is this a problem?

How can I solve this issue? Is there an alternative way to check for existation of registry key with powershell custom action?

```
$registryPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
$keyName = "AutoAdminLogon"
if (Test-Path $registryPath)
{
    # The following line returns FALSE when executed during installation and TRUE when executed manually.
    $valueExists = (Get-ItemProperty $registryPath).PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $keyName
    if ($valueExists)
    {
        # Set property to be read in installshield
        Set-Property -Name IS_AUTO_LOGON -Value 2
    }
    else
    {
        Set-Property -Name IS_AUTO_LOGON -Value 1
    }           
 }
```

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @PetSerAl my os? 64-bit.

Comment: Are you manually executing 64-bit version of PowerShell? Are installer executing 64-bit version of PowerShell?

Comment: I'm not sure what version installer executing. How can I check it? But why does it matter? I'm giving a specific and hard coded registry path in the script..

Comment: `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`. If you thinking that 32-bit and 64-bit application asking for the same registry path always get the same registry key, then you are wrong.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ok, it seems like this is really the problem, Installshield opens a 32 bit version of Powershell which can't find the relevant key. How can I tell it to run the 64bit version? Or is there other workaround?

Comment: Powershell needs the .NET runtime to run properly - not great (yet). I would strongly recommend using Installscript instead which runs without dependencies (finally). You should get a flying start looking at ``C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2016\Samples\WindowsInstaller\Sample Script Project`` (path for a standard IS 2016 install - search for ``ScriptSamples.ism`` if you can't find it). Plenty of Installscript sample code here (look in the function QueryRegistry) to get you a much better custom action than what you get with managed code. Not an answer for you, just an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Installshield indeed opens up the 32 bit version of powershell.
So I simply asked to get the 64 bit version of the registry at the beginning of the script and then checked if the required key is there.

In order to get the 64 bit version of registry and search for my key I used:

```
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView]::Registry64)
$subKey =  $key.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon")
$isAutoLogon = $subKey.GetValue("AutoAdminLogon")
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to do this with Powershell. Windows installer can do this natively with the [RegLocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx) table.

Comment: InstallShield exposes these in the Behavior and Logic > System Search view.

Comment: Agreed, I guess it depends what other operations he needs to implement? If he needs more features, even VBScript would be better than Powershell for reliability imho. Until the .NET framework is hosted by msiexec.exe, managed code will always be unsafe I think. Also, Installscript runs without any runtime requirements at long last, so I think it is preferable overall - despite being an obtuse language by now - somewhat complex, and for little gain.